# Ruby SQL to arel query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am looking to create a query within the scope that will search for records that have a date less than or equal to the current date. I understand how to do this in SQL but I'm not sure how this would translate over to this. Currently all I have is this

```
scope :index_overdue, -> { where(active: true, end_date: nil).order(arel_table[:complete_by], arel_table[:latest_update_date], arel_table[:id]) }
```

I need the query to only retrieve records that have a complete_by date that is <= The current date.

Comment: you have records set with a `complete_by` in the future? why are you using Arel in the `#order` method?

Comment: try `where(arel_table[:your_date].lteq(Date.today))` which uses [arel predications](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/Arel/Predications) or `where('your_date <= ?', Date.today)` for a simpler syntax

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [beginless range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#class-Range-label-Beginless-2FEndless+Ranges) to write that condition:

```
scope :index_overdue, -> { 
  where(active: true, end_date: nil, complete_by: ..Date.today)
    .order(...) 
}
```